# How to set array of array in one single array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I want to make single array from array of array. i have tried by following code but there is not output display that i want.

following is my array.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 78
                    [user_id] => 11
                    [product_id] => 98
                    [qty] => 3
                    [size] => 10
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 79
                    [user_id] => 11
                    [product_id] => 99
                    [qty] => 3
                    [size] => 10
                )

        )

)
```

And I want following type

```
Array
(

        [0] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 78
                [user_id] => 11
                [product_id] => 98
                [qty] => 3
                [size] => 10
            )


        [1] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 79
                [user_id] => 11
                [product_id] => 99
                [qty] => 3
                [size] => 10
            )


)
```

My code is following but it's not work

```
$getResult = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM mytable");
foreach ($getResult as $key => $value) {
    $value->id;
}
```

Anyone know how to do this ? Please help me how to do this

Comment: I would START by looking at how you created the first array and fix that to make the array how you want it

Comment: Your code isn't actually _doing_ anything. You're not assigning anything, modifying anything, or even outputting anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Merge the upper level arrays into one:

```
$result = call_user_func_array('array_merge', $array);
```

I don't know Wordpress, but maybe there is something other than `get_results` that will return the array the way that you want it?

Answer (score 0):

Because your each array has only one array You can try this code:

```
foreach ($unwantedArrayFormat as $upperArray) {
    $correctlyFormattedArray[] = $upperArray[0];
}
```